# Bounding the camera to the map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have a 2D game in unity, and I have a camera that follow my main character.
Currently, when I, for example, move the character to the left, I can see what's beyond the map, like so:

[image: map out of bounds]

Say the map size is 15X15. I have a script generating 15X15 blocks of size 1X1, meaning the map bounds are (-1, -1) -> (15, 15).

There are two things I want to accomplish:
1) Have the camera not go out of the map bounds
2) When the map size is SMALLER than the camera, have the camera change its size.

Example for point 2)

The map is 5 columns and 15 rows, thus it's very narrow compared to the camera, like so:

[image: map narrow]

or even 10 columns and 3 rows, like so:

[image: map small]

I would want the size of the camera to change so it won't be neither wider or taller than the map.

How do I do those two things?

[This is the github to the current scripts in the game](https://github.com/gioragutt/GameOfThrowsUnity/tree/master/GameOfThrows/Assets/Scripts). The `CameraController` script is where the additions are supposed to be

Comment: So you basically dont want the player to see the (now) blue parts of the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthographic size defines half of the vertical size, the horizontal size is based on aspect ratio.

From there you can define what should be the biggest value when centered.

The script below should get you going. As long as your level are rectangle (that obviously includes square), it will go fine:

```
public float speed = 2f;
public Transform min;
public Transform max;
private float aspect;
private float maxSize;

private void Start () 
{
    this.aspect = Camera.main.aspect;
    this.maxSize = max.position.x <= max.position.y ? max.position.x /2f / this.aspect :max.position.y / 2f;
}

private void Update () 
{
    float size = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    Camera.main.orthographicSize += size;
    if (Camera.main.orthographicSize > maxSize) 
    {
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = maxSize;
    }

    float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float y = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
    position.x += x * Time.deltaTime * this.speed;
    position.y += y * Time.deltaTime * this.speed;
    float orthSize = Camera.main.orthographicSize;

    if (position.x < (this.min.position.x + orthSize * this.aspect)) 
    {
        position.x = this.min.position.x + orthSize * this.aspect;
    } 
    else if (position.x > (this.max.position.x - orthSize * this.aspect)) 
    {
        position.x = this.max.position.x - orthSize * this.aspect;
    }
    if (position.y < (this.min.position.y + orthSize))
    {
        position.y = this.min.position.y + orthSize;
    }
    else if(position.y > (this.max.position.y - orthSize)) 
    {
        position.y = this.max.position.y - orthSize;
    }
    this.transform.position = position;
}
```

the idea is that you have two empty game objects place at bottom left and upper right. Bottom left is dragged into min and upper right goes int max. The speed variable is just how fast the camera translates. This is attached to the camera object. There is no limit for min size of camera, but you can do it.

The point is just that you get this going for your own project as this is more generic.

The rest is just considering the camera position, current size and aspect ratio (you cannot change that at runtime or you'd have to modify the code).

EDIT:
If you wish to bound the camera zoom to the movement,remove the first lines about size and add the following after you get the horizontal/vertical movement:

```
if (x != 0f || y != 0f) {
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = Mathf.MoveTowards (Camera.main.orthographicSize, largeSize,  Time.deltaTime);
} else {
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = Mathf.MoveTowards (Camera.main.orthographicSize, size, Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Think of declaring the size, largeSize variables and set them to your need.

Comment: Hey dude, thanks a lot. I took the code you game me and modified it to work with my map, and it works. I also like the addition of the zoom-in and zoom-out option. Thanks for showing me how to do that!

Comment: Code's on github, as always